# How to transfer arguments to the properties file from annotation attribute

Tags: properties

I have next code

```
@FeignClient(name="open-exchange", url="https://openexchangerates.org/api")
public interface CurrencyRatesServiceProxy {
    @GetMapping("/latest.json?app_id=9968744ca3284c3baf5d09cf1815ae6b")
    public CurrencyRatesBean retrieveLatestCurrencyRates();

    @GetMapping("/historical/{date}.json?app_id=9968744ca3284c3baf5d09cf1815ae6b")
    public CurrencyRatesBean retrieveCurrencyRatesByDate(@PathVariable String date);

}
```

How to transfer values of annotation attributes to the properties file  ?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy -

```
@FeignClient(name="${currency.rates.api.name}", url="${currency.rates.api.url}")
public interface CurrencyRatesServiceProxy {
    @GetMapping("${currency.rates.latest}")
    public CurrencyRatesBean retrieveLatestCurrencyRates();

    @GetMapping("${currency.rates.by.date}")
    public CurrencyRatesBean retrieveCurrencyRatesByDate(@PathVariable String date);

}
```